SignalR connection throws ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on connection (self-signed cert)
I am developing an application and I am using self-signed certificate.
Everything works fine until I try to connect to signalR hub.
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.signalingHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('https://192.168.1.105:5142/signaling', {

    })
    .build();
}

I can't connect to hub if I am using my static IP address.
Browser throws ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error.
however, it connects well if I write (https://localhost:5050)
I've tried to generate certificates properly, but still getting this error. Is there any configuration to say signalR to skip certificate validation?
and this is how I create my certificate
[req]
default_bits = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = req_ext
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = AU
stateOrProvinceName = NSW
localityName = Sydney
organizationName = Self-signed certificate
commonName = 192.168.1.10

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1 = 192.168.1.10


Did you examine your certificate to see what CN and subject alt names it actually has?

Do you mean you want to always recognize the SSL certificate as successfully validated in the SignalR Core client?

thanks guy, I have fix it by changing the certificate's CN.
